# Thinkpad L520 randomly freezes

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, freeze, thinkpad

My Lenovo Thinkpad L520 keeps randomly freezing. It totally locks up so that even STRG+ALT+DELETE does not help and there is no bluescreen. The only thing left is the fixed screen and only hard shutdown helps. The Windows events do not display anything wrong except that the system was not properly shutdown. (I guess that is because it locks up so suddenly and totally, that not even log output can be written.) It runs on Windows 8.1 64 Bit with the newest BIOS. A Lenovo Solution Center Hardware-scan did not find problems. The Laptop is not hot from the underside and it happens even without significant system usage, e.g. when only browsing the internet or watching a flash movie. CPU temperature in that case is about 50 °C as measured by RealTemp 3.70.

Comment: 50 degrees F or C. If it is C, that is really hot.

Comment: (1) On [this thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/bsod-help-support/217545-lenovo-t420-random-freeze-shutdown.html) the solution was to uninstall RapidBoot Shield. (2) Have also a look at [these workarounds](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1303739). Otherwise: (3) Are you able to test the computer in Safe Mode and see if the freezing happens? (4) Does it happen under both battery and mains power?

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013 50 degrees Celsius.

Comment: @harrymc It happens under both battery and mains power. I don't have RapidBoot Shield installed.

Comment: So it's not the power-supply. You could try to (1) install the latest [Intel HD Graphics 3000 driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=&ProductID=3319&ProdId=3319). (2) fully patch the computer including optional Windows Updates (except bing etc.), (3) monitor the GPU temperature, for example using [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/2418/techpowerup-gpu-z-v0-8-0/) (if it works on integrated Intel).

Answer (score 1):

If you are running windows 8. Just back up all your data and re install windows 8 or may be refresh windows with out losing your data. This might help you.
And check your laptop's fan does it work or not.
Use Lenovo Energy management and click Dust Removal.
That helps your laptop to clean the Dust in you fan and cool down the temperature of your laptop.

Answer (score 1):

That laptop is quite old it is ? How long you've used ?

Me also facing the same problem , im using Inspiron R14 . Sometimes when im just playing FB games or watching youtube it went super laggy and then auto shutdown. I've tried to clean the laptop from the inside and outside and ensure there is no virus that keeps the temperature high.

From what I know , when the laptop is used for long time , the material called thermal paste under heatsink of cooler of your processor will dry out. So the solution are :

1. Replace the thermal paste under the heatsink of processor's cooler

Or just do like me , buy a laptop cooler and put desk fan direct to the direction of your laptop heatsink .

I've settled the problem and able to play 'heavy' games until nowadays.

Comment: I have been using the laptop since start of 2011. I don't want to buy an external cooler but I will definitely switch out the termal paste.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fingerprint sensor on your notebook try to deactivate it or uninstall the drivers. I had a thinkpad where the fingerprint sensor drivers were the cause of freezing.